# How to verify title of header in NativeStack?

Tags: react-native, testing, react-navigation, testing-library

I'm trying to test the value of the header when using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/testing) with a `NativeStack` but when I try to do something like

```
const title = queryByText('Title');
expect(title).toBeTruthy();
```

The value returned is `null`.